# Using Log4Cocoa for multithreading app

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, logging, log4j

I start using the Log4Cocoa library in my app, but i search  other way to configure the the logger.

```
+ (void) configureWithFile:(NSString*)pathLogFile
{
    L4PropertyConfigurator* configurator = [[L4PropertyConfigurator alloc] pathLogFile];
    [configurator configure];
    [configurator release];
}
```

This function will be called only once time in  the main app for all the logger, but i want change this solution in order calling this function in the init of logger and not calling it in the main.
Thanks